# I want to display those images on next page :Django

Tags: python, html, django

i want to open those images on next page

[image: xx]

but showing me this error : page not found

[image: xx]

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf.urls import url
#from .views import VrPageView
from . import views`

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='listings'),
    path('<int:listing_id>', views.listing, name='listing'),
    path('search', views.search, name='search'),
    #path('listings/',VrPageView.as_view(),name='vr.html'),
    path('/<int:listing_id>/vr.html', views.vr, name='vr'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from .choices import price_choices, bedroom_choices, state_choices
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .models import Listing

def vr(request,listing_id):
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=listing_id)
    context = {'listing': listing}
    return render(request,'listings/vr.html',context)'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the [help] and [ask].

Comment: read the django docs on url patterns